# Removing duplicate value in array using .filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove duplicate values in an array. As I was searching I found that I could use .filter() for the solution. Following code seems to work, but I don't understand how `return array.indexOf( value ) === index;` part works. Can someone explain what that part mean? So far I understand that .filter() returns values that is true.

```
var items = [3,2,2,4,8,8,8,6,9];

var result = items.filter( function( value, index, array ) {

    return array.indexOf( value ) === index;

})

console.log( result );
```

Comment: It's only keeping the elements that are found in their same position.  So if a value appears twice, the second instance will find the first instance index, not match, and be excluded

Comment: Just look at every single step and combine them. What does `array.indexOf(value)` do? What does `array.indexOf(value) === index` do and what is the result? How does `.filter()` work?